# Animate Height from Bottom to Top

Tags: html, css

I'm having troubles animating change in height from bottom to top. Currently, the entire legend itself gets pushed down as the height of each color changes: http://jsfiddle.net/b7q9781o/

How can I make it so the legend stays at its position and the height changes from its base (bottom) to top?

If I add `float: left;` to `#holder`, it kind of works the way I want to but it gets flipped. Try it.

```
#holder {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10em;
    display: block;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
.legend {
    height: 5px;
    width: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:

```
#holder {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10em;
    display: block;
    height: 150px;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/b7q9781o/1/)

Comment: It still pushes the entire legend down as the height changes. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: I have one idea please wait a minutes sir@mapr